# Не работает переключение radio button при одинаковом name

Tags: html

Всем привет! Помогите разобраться - не хочет снимать выделение с предыдущего значения, при смене выбора код:

```
<form action="mailto:romanenko83@gmail.com" enctype="text/plain" method="post" 
  style="width:65%; margin:0 auto">
      <!--НЕ РАБОТАЕТ ПЕРЕКЛЮЧАЛКА-->
      <label for="question">Are you a medical manufacturer?</label>
      <input type="radio" value="yes" name:"question">YES
      <input type="radio" value="no" name:"question">NO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name:"question"` - почему вдруг двоеточие, а не "равно"?

```html
<label for="question">Are you a medical manufacturer?</label>
<input type="radio" value="yes" name="question">YES
<input type="radio" value="no" name="question">NO
```

Comment: Учусь, потому и ошибаюсь, Спасибо - работает!